stanza.js xmpp +esm cdn typeError
I am having issues with connecting to my Prosody server using the stanza +esm cdn dist.
The websocket connection works with a standard WebSocket object connection in the HTML file (see first script) however the second script using Stanza cdn errors.
The wss connection works fine with stanza package in a node script. I just can't get it to work with cdn ESM link in a standard, standalone HTML file. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Connection error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
at new ti (_stream_duplex.js:58:14)
at new Oh (websocket.js:9:9)
at Kh.connect (Client.js:300:31)
at index.html:22:16


HTML file:
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stanza.js +ESM</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    // this works
        const socket = new WebSocket('wss://test.com:5281/xmpp-websocket', 'xmpp');
        socket.onopen = () => console.log('Connected!');
        socket.onerror = (err) => console.error('WebSocket Error:', err);
    </script>
     <script type="module">
    // this errors
        import * as stanza from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/stanza@12.20.0/+esm'

        const client = stanza.createClient({
            jid: 'user@test.com',
            password: 'password',
            resource: 'web',
            transports: {
                websocket: 'wss://test.com:5281/xmpp-websocket'
            }
        });

        console.log(client);
        console.log(client.config);

        client.on('session:started', () => {
            console.log('Stanza Connected');
            client.getRoster();
            client.sendPresence();
        });

        client.on('chat', msg => {
            console.log('Received chat:', msg);
        });

        client.connect().catch(err => {
            console.error('Connection error:', err);
        });

        client.on('connected', () => console.log('Connected to XMPP server'));

        function sendMessage() {
            client.sendMessage({
                to: 'user1@test.com',
                body: 'Hello from Stanza WEB!',
                type: 'chat'
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>```

